# How to remove span message and error class in on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to remove this message.

```
<span class="hidden-480">
<span class="help-block error" for="pwidth">Please enter a positive integer (or) six decimal number.</span>
<span class="help-block error" for="pheight">Please enter a positive integer (or) six decimal number.</span>
```

anyone answer this question

Comment: What do you even mean? Do you just want to remove the error class using javascript? Add jQuery to your project and do something like $('span').removeClass('error');

Comment: `onchange` on which element?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove error class on single span. so yo have to give id to span like

```
<span id="span1" class="help-block error" for="pwidth">Please enter a positive integer (or) six decimal number.</span>
```

then using JavaScript

```
$('#span1').removeClass('error');
```

and if you want to remove class from all span then

```
 $('span).removeClass('error');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass) to remove `error` and add `hide` class when you entered a valid number,

```js
$(function() {
  $('#inptWidth').on('change', function() {
    // you validation here
    var state = Number(this.value) > 0;
    $('span[for=pwidth]').toggleClass('error', !state).toggleClass('hide',state);
  });
});
```

```css
span {
  display: block
}

.error {
  color: red
}

.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="hidden-480">
  <span class="help-block error" for="pwidth">Please enter a positive integer (or) six decimal number for width.</span>
</span>
<input id="inptWidth" placeholder="Width" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
  $('span).removeClass('error');
});
```